# Trying to restrict Jenkins access to specified group in FreeIPA

Tags: linux, jenkins, freeipa

========== IPA config ==========

[image]

========== Jenkins config ==========

[image]
[image]

========== Jenkins warning (user in "jenkins-usergroup") ==========

[image]

========== Jenkins warning (user not in "jenkins-usergroup") ==========

[image]

====================

Two issues:

(1) The warning itself.

(2) Jenkins is allowing any user that's in IPA; not just those in "jenkins-usergroup", which is what I'm aiming for.

Comment: "Group search base: `ou=jenkins-usergroup`" - that doesn't seem right to me.  What's the DN of your jenkins group?

Comment: I would expect your group search base to look something more like `OU=Groups,DC=test,DC=lan`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

On IPA, created user "jenkins" and added to "jenkins-usergroup" (for use as manager dn/password below)

=== Jenkins settings ===

Security Realm

> LDAP
>
> > server: ldap://ipa01.test.lan
> >
> > root dn: dc=test,dc=lan
> >
> > user search base: cn=users,cn=accounts
> >
> > uid={0}
> >
> > group search base: (BLANK)
> >
> > group search filter: (BLANK)
> >
> > group membership: "search for ldap groups containing user"
> >
> > > group membership filter: (BLANK)
> >
> > manager dn: uid=jenkins,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=test,dc=lan
> >
> > manager password: (PASSWORD I SET FOR "jenkins" IN IPA)
> >
> > display name ldap attribute: displayname
> >
> > email address ldap attribute: mail

Authorization

> > matrix-based security
> >
> > > user/group
> > >
> > > > Anonymous - uncheck all permissions
> > > >
> > > > jenkins-usergroup - check all permissions (or whatever you want)